# SSRS Report Fixed Width & Column break

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I'm using a Matrix inside my Report with Dynamic Rows & Columns, and of course more columns means increasing Width, So Is there is any way I can have a Column Break after 'N' number of columns so I can maintain the Report Width to be Printable on A4 Paper or whatever size I want.

Have in mind that I Followed this Question answer : 
[Limit no of columns in SSRS matrix report](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/32f28407-e1ca-457e-92fd-d292e32dde4e/)

to have a Column break after N number of Columns, but it's working only for Fixed Rows, Dynamic Rows it will not.

any Ideas Guys, appreciated
Thanks,

Comment: Would setting the overreaching rows to "NoGrow" help?

Answer (score 0):

The report width automatically grows as needed when there are more columns. When you go to print, it will automatically break the extra columns onto another page. The only setting that you really have control over regarding this is the Keep Together on one page if Possible one, which doesn't apply in this situation. The CanGrow option doesn't apply to column widths.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the matrix inside List, 
make sure the list is larger than the matrix, adjust the size of the list well. 
limit the number of rows "=Ceiling(RowNumber(nothing)/x)" -in this case, it will limit the dynamic column numbers
If the numbers of column exceed x, it will go down to next line.
Remember to remove sorting inside group setting.